# AJAX JSON array to single JSON object

Tags: html, json, ajax, post, request

I'm using AJAX to send JSON data from a form to my server, however it's sending it as an array of JSON values, rather than just a single JSON object - how can I modify this script to send it as a single object?

```
function send() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:1323/submitted",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeArray())
    });
}
```

For example, instead of sending it as:

```
[{"name":"name","value":"boris"},{"name":"password","value":"password123"}]
```

I'd like to send it as:

```
{"name":"boris", "password":"password123"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through all inputs and push `name` and `value` inside JSON Object.

***Demo code***:

```js
function send() {
  var json_object = {};
  //loop through inputs
  $("#myform input").each(function(i, v) {
    json_object[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val() //get values

  })
  console.log(json_object)
  //or 
  var json_object1 = {}
  $($("#myform").serializeArray()).each(function(i, v) {
    json_object1[v.name] = v.value
  })
  console.log(json_object1)
  //send this..
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input name="name" type="text">
  <input name="password" type="text">
  <button type="button" onclick="send()">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is closer to what I want, however now content of the request is: name=boris&password=password123 rather than {"name":"boris", "password":"password123"} - which I'd prefer as my server accepts JSON

Comment: Hi, use `JSON.stringify()` like you where doing in your previous code and then send that to your server.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.